# InCorrect Column binding in excel after changing the column order in datatable

Tags: c#

i have datatable like below.

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.columns.Add("ColumnA");
dt.Columns.Add("ColumnB");
```

i'm printing the same column in the file sheet using below code.

```
private void GetColumns(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();


            for (int i= 0; i< dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName);
                sb.Append(",");
            }

            new wrapper().workbook=sb.ToString();
    }
```

so in my file initially columns was appearing in the order ColumnA  & ColumnB,
Now if i change the datatable columns order as below.

```
dt.Columns.Add("ColumnB");
dt.Columns.Add("ColumnA");
```

even now im getting as same order like ColumnA & ColumnB.

i need a result like ColumnB & ColumnA.

please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change order of columns

```
dt.Columns["A"].SetOrdinal(1);
```